# Size issue while processing very larger size documents in SPARK using python

Tags: python, hadoop, apache-spark, warnings, pyspark

I have used python script to process xml documents stored in hdfs using SPARK.

```
files = sc.wholeTextFiles("hdfs://xxx/data").collect()
```

Here the /data directory have more than 10,000 xml documents. I have to process all the documents using SPARK. But while i am trying to run, i got the below error message:

```
WARN TaskSetManager: Stage 0 contains a task of very large size (451 KB). The maximum recommended task size is 100 KB
```

How to rectify this error. Can anyone please help me to fix this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Here am just using single machine to process (using SPARK). I am able to use parallel mechanism for this?

Comment: I have got the answer now. I have maximizes the partition by using the following code: files = sc.wholeTextFiles("hdfs://xxx/data",10).collect()

Answer (score 0):

I have got the answer now. I have maximizes the partition by using the following code: `files = sc.wholeTextFiles("hdfs://xxx/data",10).collect()`